# How to run a custom view with three-argument version constructor on pre-Honeycomb devices?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-custom-view

I have a custom view that extends LinearLayout with the following contructors:

```
public VoiceRecorderLayout(Context context)
{
    this(context, null);
}

public VoiceRecorderLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public VoiceRecorderLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
{       
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;   
    loadViews();    
}
```

My application crashes only iff I run it on the devices or emulator with api lower than 11.
The reason of the crash is a three argument constructor as I found on android developers google group:

```
**"The three-argument version of LinearLayout constructor is only available with API 11 and higher -- i.e. Android 3.0.
This dependency has to be satisfied at runtime by the actual Android version running on the device."**
```

Is there a way that I can use this view in the older devices such as with android 2.3.3?

Here is a logcat:

```
11-15 13:34:20.121: E/AndroidRuntime(408): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-15 13:34:20.121: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-15 13:34:20.121: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
11-15 13:34:20.121: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
11-15 13:34:20.121: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  ... 21 more
11-15 13:34:20.121: E/AndroidRuntime(408): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>
11-15 13:34:20.121: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at edu.neiu.voiceofchicago.support.VoiceRecorderLayout.<init>(VoiceRecorderLayout.java:102)
11-15 13:34:20.121: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  at edu.neiu.voiceofchicago.support.VoiceRecorderLayout.<init>(VoiceRecorderLayout.java:97)
11-15 13:34:20.121: E/AndroidRuntime(408):  ... 24 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases like this, it is easier not to chain the constructors, and place your custom setup code into an `init()` style method so that you don't have to try and branch your code based on platform version.

```
public VoiceRecorderLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public VoiceRecorderLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public VoiceRecorderLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {       
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    this.context = context;   
    loadViews();    
}
```

Comment: I felt I was missing something... Since the LogCat clearly shows two constructor calls, this approach makes more sense. (upvote)

Comment: There's no need to pass the `Context` parameter, you can get it via `getContext()`.